# Aggregate imports then export in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm used to using ES6 syntax. I tend to aggregate my React Component files into one "import" file which I use as the index.js of my Components folder. This allows me to write destructing imports like so:

```
import { App, Ticker, Timer } from "./components"
```

Inside of my index.js file I can easily write export from import commands like so:

```
export App from "./app"
export Ticker from "./ticker"
export Timer from "./timer"
```

Is there a way I can do this in TypeScript? I can't seem to get index.ts to be recognized as the default file in a module. Is there also any syntax to export an import in TypeScript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a way I can do this in TypeScrip

Just use the es6 `export *` syntax:

```
export * from "./components";
```

Alternatively you can still do:

```
export {App,Ticker,Timer} from "./compoents"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add curly braces like so:

```
export { App } from "./app";
export { Ticker } from "./ticker";
export { Timer } from "./timer";
```

Hope it helped